# Firebase Test Lab Errors for Instrumentation Test

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-uiautomator, firebase-test-lab

I am new to Android development. I am creating a black box test with UIAutomator and another app in Android Studio 3.0. I want to run this in the Google Firebase Testlab. I am getting a TON of warnings/errors which I don't know how to handle.
Here is my code in `project/app/src/androidTest/java/com.firebaseapp.test_test.test/ExampleInstrumentedTest.java`:

```
//This code doesn't wait for elements to appear, doesnt do error handling/reporting, etc.
//Its just a proof of concept of running in firebase test lab, which it doesnt
package com.firebaseapp.test_test.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.By;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiSelector;
import android.support.test.uiautomator.Until;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()); //assign device

        assertEquals("com.firebaseapp.test_test.test", appContext.getPackageName()); //idk, this was here by default
        Intent intent = appContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.testapp.android"); //look for testapp
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //if testapp is currently running, close it
        appContext.startActivity(intent); //start testapp
        mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg("com.testapp.android")), 30); //make sure testappstarted correctly

        mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.testapp.android:id/log_in")).clickAndWaitForNewWindow(); //Click log in button
        mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.testapp.android:id/login_user")).setText("username"); //fill in username
        mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.testapp.android:id/pass")).setText("password"); //Fill in password
        mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.testapp.android:id/next_btn")).clickAndWaitForNewWindow(); //Click sign in, wait
    }

}
```

Here is my manifest XML in `project/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.firebaseapp.root_registrar.rootregistrar">
    <uses-sdk
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/> //idk if this is the right version, just found it online
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</manifest>
```

Here are are my errors (excludes all normal logs/warnings, that would exceed this post's limits:
[image: Errors]

I tried building the instrumented test APK alone. I tried building it for debugging. I tried building it for release. I tried building it with a signature. I'd get various errors before even running it in Test Lab, saying the test APK doesn't have a valid signature, or the test APK doesnt contain the test runner class specified in the manifest file. I am really just confused by all this application signing, manifest files, and random-seeming errors from Test Lab (despite ExampleInstrumentation.java running the test fine in Android Studio on Nexus 5 Android 7.0)

**I guess my question is broad. What should I do to make this black box test apk run along my testapp's APK in the Firebase Test Lab as an Instrumentation Test?**

Comment: Do you know what's generating those errors?  Are they failing your tests in a specific way?  They don't look specific to Test Lab.

Comment: That's what is confusing me. Most do not seem relevant to my app, but I don't know if I am setting up my test apk correctly either.

Comment: Im beginning to think its a permissions error from research

Comment: If it's not failing your test, then you probably don't have anything to worry about.  It's probably a preloaded app failing.